# Soft wdt reset on ESP8266 when using Speed Sensor

Tags: mqtt, sensors, esp8266, reset, watchdog

I'm on my personal project to create a esp8266 module that can read several sensor from a vehicle and it can sends data over mqtt. so I have written the code where I try to reading the speed sensor its getting wdt reset and the esp8266 resetting again

so heres my code

```
void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(speedSensor,INPUT_PULLUP);

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  
  while (WiFi.begin(ssid, pass) != WL_CONNECTED) {
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Connecting to");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("the network");
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(5000);
  }
  lcd.clear();

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  Serial.println();

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Connected to");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("the network");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();

  // attempt to connect to the MQTT broker:
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to the MQTT broker: ");
  Serial.println(broker);

  if (!mqttClient.connect(broker, port)) {
    Serial.print("MQTT connection failed! Error code = ");
    Serial.println(mqttClient.connectError());

    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the MQTT broker!");
  Serial.println();

  // subscribe to the topic and set callback function
  mqttClient.onMessage(SwitchMotor);
  mqttClient.subscribe(topicSwitchMotor);

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Connected to");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("the MQTT broker");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(" Fuel :");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(" RPM  :");

  SPI.begin();
  rfid.PCD_Init();
  Serial.println("I am waiting for card...");
  pinMode(pinRelay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinRelay, HIGH);
}

void loop() {

  mqttClient.poll(); // check for incoming messages

  FuelSensor(); // Fuel Sensor
  SpeedMotor(); // Speed Sensor
  StartMotor(); // Start Motor with RFID
}

void SpeedMotor(){
  start_time=millis();
  end_time=start_time+1000;
  
  while(millis()<end_time){
    yield();
      if(digitalRead(speedSensor)){
          steps=steps+1; 
          while(digitalRead(speedSensor));
      }
  }

  // calculate the speed
  temp=steps-steps_old;
  steps_old=steps;
  rps=(temp/20);
  rpm=(rps*60);
  lcd.setCursor(9,1);
  lcd.print(rpm);
  lcd.print("   ");

  // publish the message
  mqttClient.beginMessage(topicSpeedRpm);
  mqttClient.print(rpm);
  mqttClient.endMessage();

  mqttClient.beginMessage(topicSpeedRps);
  mqttClient.print(rps);
  mqttClient.endMessage();
}
```

and this is the output from serial monitor

```
Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: cieciecie
...You're connected to the network

Attempting to connect to the MQTT broker: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
You're connected to the MQTT broker!

I am waiting for card...

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffde0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01a0
3fffff80:  3fffdad0 3ffee7bc 3ffee7c0 40201143  
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeeaa8 402016e9  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeeaa8 40205d5c  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8600 40100e61  
<<<stack<<<

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
⸮⸮Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: cieciecie
...You're connected to the network

Attempting to connect to the MQTT broker: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
You're connected to the MQTT broker!

I am waiting for card...

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Soft WDT reset
```

it'll soft wdt reset all over again and again

I'd already try Stack ESP execption decoder and it given this results
[ESP Exception decoder results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGhkv.png)

at the results its mentioning line 152 at speedMotor() function

```
void SpeedMotor(){
  start_time=millis();
  end_time=start_time+1000;
  
  while(millis()<end_time){
    yield(); // already use yield(); on while() loop
      if(digitalRead(speedSensor)){ // line 152
          steps=steps+1; 
          while(digitalRead(speedSensor));
      }
  }

  // calculate the speed
  temp=steps-steps_old;
  steps_old=steps;
  rps=(temp/20);
  rpm=(rps*60);
  lcd.setCursor(9,1);
  lcd.print(rpm);
  lcd.print("   ");

  // publish the message
  mqttClient.beginMessage(topicSpeedRpm);
  mqttClient.print(rpm);
  mqttClient.endMessage();

  mqttClient.beginMessage(topicSpeedRps);
  mqttClient.print(rps);
  mqttClient.endMessage();
}
```

and i already try too from arduino forum https://forum.arduino.cc/t/solved-esp8266-millis-crash/636543
it says try using `yield();` in the `while()` loop but its still given the soft wdt rest

i would like to have clear answer how to use the `yield();` function properly so theres no more soft wdt resetting again

Comment: My guess is that the issue may be `while(digitalRead(speedSensor));` (there is no yield in this loop and we don't have any info re how long `digitalRead(speedSensor)` will return true). Adding a bit more logging would help you trace the issue; you should also aim for a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so try removing all MQTT related code and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: so it would be look like this? ```while(digitalRead(speedSensor)) {
    yield();
}
```

Comment: Yes (I'm not guaranteeing that is the issue but it is an issue..)

Comment: Yes, Thats the issue, after im adding `yield();` it wont resetting anymore, thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments the issue was in this section of code:

```
 while(millis()<end_time){
    yield(); // already use yield(); on while() loop
      if(digitalRead(speedSensor)){ // line 152
          steps=steps+1; 
          while(digitalRead(speedSensor));
      }
  }
```

The problem  is that if `digitalRead(speedSensor)` returns true then a loop runs until `digitalRead(speedSensor)` returns `false`; this may run long enough to trigger the watchdog.

```
while(digitalRead(speedSensor));
```

One way of fixing this is to `yield` within the loop i.e.:

```
while(digitalRead(speedSensor)) {
     yield(); 
}
```